# .Net API for accessing MuZ

Tags: z3

The tutorial at rise4fun mentions a .Net API for accessing MuZ. However, clicking on any of the mentioned methods, eg `To add a rule, call: Z3_datalog_add_rule` leads to a dead link. Where are these methods described and are they currently supported?

Also, not directly related to this question, but i notice that the examples, which presumably use the SMT-LIB API use a `define-fun` command. Is there an equivalent function available in the .Net API?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reporting the broken links.

The link:

```
http://rise4fun.com/Z3/tutorialcontent/group__capi.html#ga0d158891352456e6a4ac9ba398a75653
```

Should have pointed to:

```
 http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/group__capi.html
```

The corresponding link to .NET API functions is:

```
 http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/class_microsoft_1_1_z3_1_1_context.html
```

Note that in the latest versions of Z3, 
the .NET API has undergone significant revisions over the version used in rise4fun.
The link above describes the up-to-date .NET API.
A link to the "legacy" .NET API used in previous versions of Z3 is:

```
http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/old/group__mapi.html
```

These links are collected on: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/

The declare functions, the .NET API in the newest version is called "MkFuncDecl". It is a method on a context object. It has several overloads:

```
 FuncDecl  MkFuncDecl (Symbol name, Sort[] domain, Sort range) 
 FuncDecl  MkFuncDecl (Symbol name, Sort domain, Sort range) 
 FuncDecl  MkFuncDecl (string name, Sort[] domain, Sort range) 
 FuncDecl  MkFuncDecl (string name, Sort domain, Sort range)
```

The second link mentioned above takes you to the documentation for these functions.

Comment: thanks for the prompt response. The link you gave seems to point to the C API. I guestimated the following code ought to do the trick (from F#):    let testMuZ() =
      let ctx = new Context()
      let fp = new Fixedpoint(ctx)

Comment: thanks for the prompt response. The link you gave seems to point to the C API. Based on what the other Z3 methods look like I figured the following code ought to do the trick (in F#):   
 
      let testMuZ() =
      let ctx = new Context()
      let fp = new Fixedpoint(ctx)
      ...
However this gives me a compiler error
 
    Test.fs(134,12): error FS0509: Method or object constructor 'Fixedpoint' not found
I checked in the source code (which i did not build) and the Fixedpoint.cs class is present in the source. The compiler however seems not to think its included in the DLL

Comment: Regarding MkFuncDecl, I was aware of this method. However the example at rise4fun (Perhaps old api?) does `(define-fun odd ((x Int)) Bool (= (mod x 2) 1))` and i thought maybe something like this was accessible in the new API. Its pretty much a minor convenience over using a quantified constraint.

Comment: Hi there, I am following up because I didn't hear anything about this: could you point me to a link to where the .Net API for the FixedPoint class? My attempts to infer the .Net methods from the C API haven't been very successful :-(